# make .swf file stop working after expiry date reached

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a simple games. I've put the expiry date on it. I want to stop that .swf file from working after it reaches expiry date. So far I have only come up with creating a movieclip manually which is sitting on top of the layer. Inside that clip is two frames. First frames has nothing and the second frame have rectangle which is faded. So basically, when the swf file reaches the expiry date, it will go and stop at frame 2 and it won't let anyone to interact with the game. I don't think this is how it's done. So any help will be much appreciate. Does anyone knows how to implement the expiry date and is it possible to make .swf file working ?

Comment: Where did you put the expiry date ? if it's hard coded, you can get the actual date with the Date class and compare with your expiry date if( date >= expiryDate ) goto frame 2 else goto your game logic

Comment: I've put expiry date on main timeline and it's working fine. My problem(concern) is how should I approach after expiry date is meet.

Comment: Just remove main class off stage, and add a notice "SWF expired" to the stage instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flash's date class to read local or universal time. You can read more on how to use that [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html), and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f10.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f0c). As for the actual implementation, you could run a simple if statement when you go to init the movieclip and, at that point, switch it out for another one or whatever.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can read the time and compare it with my expiry date and it's working fine. My problem is I'm not sure putting a movieclip on top of everything just to make user from interacting with the game after it reaches the expiry date. I want my swf file to stop working completely after it reaches the expiry date. Or any other ideas how should I approach after expiry date is passed ?

Comment: Do you mean that the swf should not open or just not work as it did previously?

Comment: I would say just remove the child directly after you init it by putting in an if statement or just not init it at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with timeline code, you can make your verification on the first frame, if expiry date is not reached go to main logic game frame and if it reach expiry date go to another frame with no code in it. 
If you use Classes, you can make your verification in your Main class end after that instanciate your main logic game class in case of expiry date not reached or just do nothing in the other case.